# how to compare date array values

Tags: java, arrays, date, time

I have date array storing the date and time. It has 2 values.Both are same.

> Wed Jan 29 00:18:48 GMT 2014

When i compare them

```
    date1[1]==date1[2]
```

it returns false.

Totally Confusing. Why is it happening when they are same values.

Comment: Can you show full codes ? What is the type of array ?? Is it `String` or `Date` object ?

Comment: Date date1=new date1[2];

Comment: @Keerthana too bad way to check equality of `Object`.

Comment: `date[1].getTime()==date[2].getTime()` Is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera No, That is not a bad way. What you do if you want to check two references are equal or not ? OP confused  between `equals` and `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make you understand, if it is a `Date` array, then `Date` object should be compared using

```
Date.compareTo(Date arg)
```

If it is a String array containing the date, then it should be compared using

```
String.equals(String arg)
```

`==` is conditional test operator for checking the equality. This does the equality test by comparing the actual values in the left and right operands. So, this should be used only to test the equality of primitive values. Thus, it says avoid using `==` on testing equality on Object types

Comment: In other words, using `==` between objects tells if both references point to the same object, the same chunk of memory. Using `==` does *not* compare the contents of the data stored inside  the two objects. If this makes no sense, study up on some basic Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

To compare `Date` you can use `before()` `after()` method in `Java.util.Date`.

Similarly `Date` is also a `Java` Object, So you can use `equals()` too

```
    Date date1=new Date();
    Date date2=new Date();

    if(date1.before(date2)){
        System.out.println("date1 before date2");
    } else if(date1.after(date2)){
        System.out.println("date1 after date2");
    } else if(date1.equals(date2)){
        System.out.println("date1 and date2 equals");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Object-types are compared like this:

```
object1.equals(object2)
```

only primitives (not their wrapped Object types) are compared with the "==" operator.

However, if you want to know wheter an Object is EXACTLY the same Object (same address in memory, same reference)  you should use the "==" operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
date1[1].equals(date1[2])
```

`==` checks if the refferences are the same. you need equals, because you want to compare the content.

Answer (score 1):

use `equals` method for objects

```
date1[1].equals(date1[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the numerical values for the dates instead.  They are more reliable, especially when it comes to different date sub classes.

```
date[1].getTime()==date[2].getTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to advice you without seeing the whole code, but I think you've to use method equals() or something like that. When you use operator == on non-primitive types, you're comparing references, not values.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `==` compares the references of the object. For example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("Hello");
    if(s.toString() == "Hello")
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Will display nothing. You can use `==` to compare primitives types:

```java
int i = 5;
if(i == 5)
    System.out.println(i);
```

This will display `5`.

If you want to compare the content of 2 objects, you have to use `equals()` method:

```java
String s = "Hello";
if(s.equals("Hello"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Will display `Hello`.

Make sure the class of the object override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

If your goal is to compare the objects, the best way is to call `compareTo()`, but your class must implements `Comparable` interface.

Comment: That's not truth, actually. That first string comparison you've shown will print "Hello". It's because of some optimizations. Since that two strings are exactly the same, they're hold in memory only once and their references are the same. Try to run it, you'll see.

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry about the confusion. I edited my post to give a better example. Here the JVM does not optimize.